# Why does my Vagrant loop fail to create all VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, ruby, vagrant

With Vagrant, I aim to have three master and two node machines on my Ubuntu host.

My `Vagrantfile`:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  (1..3).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "master" do |master|
      master.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    end
  end
  (1..2).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "node" do |node|
      node.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    end
  end
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "3072"
    vb.cpus = "3"
  end
end
```

I have after `vagrant up`:

```bash
$ vagrant status
Current machine states:

master                    running (virtualbox)
node                      running (virtualbox)
```

Why did the loop fail?

Answer (score 1):

`-#{i}` was missing in both `do` loops, while everything else was ok and there was no need for further changes:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
  (1..3).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "master-#{i}" do |master|
      master.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    end
  end
  (1..2).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    end
  end
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "3072"
    vb.cpus = "3"
  end
end
```